# $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution then for $f\in C$, C is family of continous functions, $f(X_n)\rightarrow f(X)$ in distribution?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

$X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution then for $f\in C$, where f is family of continous functions, $f(X_n)\rightarrow f(X)$ in distribution?

Someone already provided a guide to how to solve this question in a previous post, but I want to make sure I understood it correctly.

Attempt. By Helly Bray Theorem the following are equivalent:

$P_n \rightarrow P $ weakly

$F_n\rightarrow F $ in distribution, i.e. $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution.

Where $P_n$ is a probability measure induced by the random variabale $X_n$ and $F_n$ is the associated distribution function of $P_n$.

So all I Need to show is that $P_{f_n} \rightarrow P_f$  weakly then $f(X_n)\rightarrow f$ in distribution. Where $P_{f_n}$ and $P_f$ are the probability measures induced by the random variables $f(X_n)$ and $f(X)$ respectively:

Attempt:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)P_{f_n}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\circ f(t)dP_n\rightarrow\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\circ f(t)dP=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)dP_f$.

By the change of value theorem and the fact that $g\circ f$ is a bounded and continous function. 
One can conclude that $P_{f_n}\rightarrow P_f$ weakly and by equivalency. $f(X_n)\rightarrow f(X)$ in distribution. Am I understanding and using the Helly Bray Theorem Correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's just the case that $g \circ f$ is bounded and continuous, when $f$ is continuous and $g$ is bounded and continuous (together with equivalence of weak convergence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in distribution iff for any bounded continuous
function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $\int h(X_{n})\,dP\rightarrow\int h(X)\,dP$.

Now, suppose that $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in distribution and let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be a continuous function. Let $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be a bounded continuous function. Since $h\circ f$ is bounded and
continuous, we have $\int(h\circ f)(X_{n})\,dP\rightarrow\int(h\circ f)(X)\,dP$.
However, $h\circ f(X_{n})=h\left(f(X_{n})\right)$ and $h\circ f(X)=h\left(f(X)\right)$.
Therefore, $f(X_{n})\rightarrow f(X)$ in distribution.

Comment: Was my solution not correct?

Comment: I did not say that you are wrong.